# Melting together and displaying multiple classes using Seaborn's boxplot

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, seaborn, boxplot

I'd like to produce a boxplot similar to that which is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42760965/side-by-side-boxplot-of-multiple-columns-of-a-pandas-dataframe). Instead of by indexing by the month I'd like to index by the Question, that is, for each of the 12 Questions produced I'd like to have each question shown along with it's particular possible classes (similar to `value_vars=["A", "B"]` in the linked example). However, instead of just having the two possible classes, "A" and "B" for each of the Questions, I'd like to have each of the classes being "1" through "5" in which each class has the number of occurrences of each of the possible question values e.g. the number of 1's, 2's etc. for each question. To try to be a little more clear, I've included a picture of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: here]

The issue that I'm having is that I don't know how to create the correct index scheme and how to melt the classes together.

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
def SeverityvsFives(df):

    df['question']= df.index.???
    df_plot = df.melt(id_vars='question', value_vars=["1","2","3","4","5"])
    sns.boxplot(x='question', y='value', hue='variable', data=df_plot)
    plt.show()

n = 500
m = 12

columnnames = [str("Question_"+ str(j+1))  for j in range(m)]
a = [[random.randint(1, 5)  for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data = a, columns = columnnames, index= ???)
SeverityvsFives(df)
```

Comment: I don't understand what the boxplot feature here is. For Q1 answer is 1 you have a certain number (or percentage in comparison to 2, 3, 4, 5) but it is still just one number. You can create a boxplot for all 12 questions because this number for 1 being chosen will differ among the 12 questions but for one question there is no distribution to plot.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I changed some of the code, I hope it will make more sense. Basically I'm having a problem indexing (I think that is where the problem is). I am trying to get all 12 questions (or whatever m =) but instead of value_vars=["A","B"] in the linked question, have value_vars=["1","2","3","4","5"] which then displays the number of 1's, 2's, 3's, 4's, and 5's for each question.

Comment: The question is understood but I have to repeat - a boxplot is not appropriate for your data. The linked question has 30 different values for "A" in "January" - the boxplot shows the distribution of these 30 distinct values. Your corresponding feature would be 1 value (the number of occurrences) for choosing "Answer 1" in "Question 1". This means, there is no distribution that the boxplot could represent. Had you another subgrouping variable (let's say age groups), a boxplot could show the distribution of "Answer 1" in "Question 1" among age groups. But this is seemingly not the case.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying now. Basically I would have to do something such as take each of the value plots 1-5 for each of the questions and plot them in respect to something (per the point of the boxplot). For example, I could look at the values for 1 in respect to, say, the overall mean of all the 1's for all the questions?